# Loading fact table from source tables are taking more time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

have wrote the below query to load the fact table and its taking 12min, please help me to improve the performance.
Its a Ordered parcel(kollie) delivery info, A order can have multiple parcels(kollies), finding the latest status & scanned details loading into temp tables and then joining on them, even i created the nonclustured index on source column still its taking 12 min for loading please suggest a better way to reduce load time

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp1 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp2 
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp3') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #temp3

SELECT t1.OrderID,
       t1.StatusID INTO #temp3
FROM NTE_CASE_Rep.dbo.OrderStatusLog t1 WITH (nolock)
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT OrderID,
          MAX(RegDate) RegDate
   FROM NTE_CASE_Rep.dbo.OrderStatusLog WITH (nolock)
   GROUP BY OrderID) t2 ON t1.OrderID = t2.OrderID
AND t1.RegDate = t2.RegDate

SELECT t1.KollieID,
       TerminalZone,
       t1.RegDate AS modifieddate INTO #temp2
FROM NTE_CASE_Rep.dbo.ScannedKollie t1 WITH (nolock)
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT KollieID,
          MAX(RegDate) AS RegDate
   FROM NTE_CASE_Rep.dbo.ScannedKollie WITH (nolock)
   GROUP BY KollieID) t2 ON t1.KollieID = t2.KollieID
AND t1.RegDate = t2.RegDate

SELECT orderid,
       KollieID,
       BoxNo,
       InsertDate,
       laststatus,
       MAX(LastStatusTime) LastStatusTime INTO #temp1
FROM NTE_CASE_Rep.dbo.TRPO_KollieID WITH (nolock)
GROUP BY orderid,
         InsertDate,
         boxno,
         KollieID,
         laststatus

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_NC_Temp1_orderid ON #Temp1(orderid, boxno)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_Temp2_KollieID ON #Temp2(KollieID)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_Temp3_orderid ON #Temp3(orderid)

INSERT INTO Facts_sending(Dim_Buyer,
                          Dim_Supplier,
                          Dim_Consignee,
                          dim_status_order,
                          Dim_Status_Kollie,
                          Dim_Date_ETD,
                          Dim_Date_ETA,
                          Dim_Date_Regdate,
                          OrderID,
                          ConsignorReference,
                          ConsigneeReference,
                          POTypeId,
                          Fraktberegningsvekt,
                          KollieID,
                          LastStatusTime,
                          ModifiedDate,
                          TerminalZone,
                          Weight,
                          KollieVollume,
                          LoadingMeters,
                          InsertDate_TRPO_Header,
                          InsertDate_KollieId,
                          InsertDate_Detail,
                          LastUpdateTime)
SELECT db.buyer,
       ds.Supplier,
       dc.Consignee,
       dss.StatusID AS dim_status_order,
       DSS2.status AS Dim_Status_Kollie,
       isnull(dd1.dato,
              format(getdate(),'yyyyMMddHHmm')) AS ETD,
       isnull(dd2.dato,
              format(getdate(),'yyyyMMddHHmm')) AS ETA,
       format(th.RegDate,
              'yyyyMMddHHmm') AS RegDate,
       th.id AS orderid,
       th.ConsignorReference,
       th.ConsigneeReference,
       th.POTypeID,
       th.Fraktberegningsvekt,
       tk.KollieID,
       tk.LastStatusTime,
       sk.modifieddate,
       sk.TerminalZone,
       th.TotalWeight,
       td.KollieVolume,
       td.LoadingMeters,
       th.InsertDate AS InsertDate_TRPO_Header,
       tk.InsertDate AS InsertDate_KollieId,
       td.InsertDate AS InsertDate_Detail,
       GETDATE() AS LastUpdateTime
FROM NTE_CASE_Rep..Trpo_Header TH WITH (nolock)
LEFT JOIN #temp1 TK ON TH.ID = TK.OrderID
LEFT JOIN NTE_CASE_Rep.dbo.TRPO_Detail TD WITH (nolock) ON TD.BoxNo = TK.BoxNo
AND tk.OrderID=td.PurchaseOrderID
LEFT JOIN #temp2 SK ON Sk.KollieID=tk.KollieID
INNER JOIN #temp3 OS ON os.OrderID=th.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.Dim_Supplier DS with(nolock) ON ds.SupplierID=TH.SupplierID
INNER JOIN dbo.Dim_Consignee DC with(nolock) ON dc.ToAddressID=th.ToAddressID
INNER JOIN dbo.Dim_Status DSS WITH (nolock) ON dss.StatusID=os.StatusID
LEFT JOIN dbo.Dim_Status DSS2 WITH (nolock) ON dss2.StatusID=tk.LastStatus
INNER JOIN dbo.[Dim_Buyer] DB WITH (nolock) ON db.buyerid=Th.BuyerID
LEFT JOIN dbo.dim_date dd1 WITH (nolock) ON dd1.dato=format(th.ETD, 'yyyyMMddHHmm')
LEFT JOIN dbo.dim_date dd2 WITH (nolock) ON dd2.dato=format(th.ETA, 'yyyyMMddHHmm')
WHERE th.insertdate>=cast('2017-05-01' AS date)
  AND th.ETD>=cast('2017-05-01' AS date)
  AND th.ETA>=cast('2017-05-01' AS date)
```

Comment: I used to avoid `(SELECT OrderID,
          MAX(RegDate) RegDate
   FROM NTE_CASE_Rep.dbo.OrderStatusLog WITH (nolock)
   GROUP BY OrderID) ` by mergin in a new table last value via a trigger. This is not a solution rigth now, but for future reports

Comment: I suggest: 1. Use real tables instead of temp tables so you can more easily troubleshoot the performance; 2. Index your temp tables on join and filter columns; 3. Give us some clues about record counts. How many records in the source tables and target tables?